# Datetime picker example in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried date time picker in jquery but jquery files not supported anyone give one example with both date and time in calendar. User enter the text-box calendar will show and user will choose date and time.

Comment: what you mean by jquery files not supported?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is about, but it sounds like you're trying to use the [jQueryUI datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) - if so, you need to include jqueryui.js as well as jquery.js

Comment: i need one example code for date-time picker.

Comment: this example will help you.
https://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/0Ltv25o8/

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried reading jQueryUi documentation?

This might help to get start

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: yes i tried this but in this example only date will display. i need date and time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin for both date and time
http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/